# Как id инпута привязать к index массива, и обработчик инпута привязывать тоже к этому id, чтобы отслеживать изменившийся элемент в "React.js"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, layout, site

Мне необходимо вывести на страницу массивов инпутов посредством "React.js" и "Typescript". Как это можно сделать ?

Comment: У Вас имееются наброски? Или Вы хотите сразу готовое решение?

Comment: Было бы неплохо самое решение, но я не имею право наглеть по отношению к Вам... Набросков, как таковых, конкретных, к сожалению, не имею...:((( Недавно постигаю данные технологии, поэтому не могусам вникнуть в этот, возможно, очень лёгкий и банальный вопрос для Вас, Дмитрий.

Comment: А что такое вообще массив инпутов? Обработчиков в реакте нет в таком виде, в каком вы знаете их в нативном js, есть состояния.

Comment: Кстати, о том как работать с инпутами в реакте написано в документации: https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Массив инпутов - это структура, где каждый элемент представляет собой некий инпут. Так понятнее будет или нет ? Значит, в состояния обработку писать или как?

Comment: Я читал её, но всё равно не могу до конца это всё понять...

Comment: Вроде разобрался во всём, но  есть один существенно важный момент: "Не подскажите, как написать метод для удаления какого-нибудь элемента?"...

Comment: `const deleteItem = id => { const newItems = itemsArray.filter(item => item.id !== id); this.setState({...this.state, items: newItems} }`

Comment: Я пробовал вот так:    public removeLevel(e: any) {
        this.setState({levels: this.state.levels.filter(level => level !== e.target.value)});

    } Можно ли как-то это исправить?...

Comment: Если `levels` это массив объектов, каждый из которых содержит `id`, а в инпуте, котором берёте `e.target.value` вводите `id` удаляемого элемента массива, то нужно делать `this.state.levels.filter(level => level.id !== e.target.value)`. Проще будет просто при удалении в функцию передать `id` элемента, как я писал выше

Comment: Хорошо, а как можно считать число с клавиатуры, которое было ведено в инпут?...

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, но не уверен, что это вас устроит:

```
this.state.arr.map((el, index)=>{
    return(<input id={index} value={el} />)
})
```

Соответственно вывод инпутов прописан должен быть render()